# I try to open users/new but I get routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, routes, controller

I am a programmer who is just starting out, but I don't know how to fix this error since I don't see any flaws in it
I need help to continue with the project

#### Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :categories, except: :show
  resources :products, path: "/"

  namespace :authentication, path: '', as: '' do
    resources :users, only: [:new, :create]
  end
end
```

#### Error Console

```
Started GET "/users/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-07-06 12:40:57 -0500
  
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Authentication::UsersController):
```

#### UsersController

```
class Authentication::UsersController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        if @user.save
            redirect_to products_path, notice: t('.created')
        else
            render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

    private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :username, :password)
    end
end
```

That I can enter users/new and see the form

Comment: Nothing obvious in the code, have you tried restarting your server? Also, what's the full path to the file where you've defined the `Authentication::UsersController` class?

Comment: it's probably a zeitwerk problem... what is the path from Rails root to users_controller.rb. I think zeitwerk is not finding the file. It should be app/controllers/authentication/users_controller.rb. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html#autoloaded-constants-and-explicit-namespaces

Comment: Try with some other namespace name

Comment: I feel like the directory your controller is in is the issue